# Convert shader from GLsl 1.50 to 1.30

Tags: opengl, shader, glsl

I'm a newbie with OpenGl and I'm stuck in following the tutorial. 
I found [this tutorial](https://open.gl/textures) with these shaders

```
// Shader sources
const GLchar* vertexSource = R"glsl(
    #version 150 core
    in vec2 position;
    in vec3 color;
    in vec2 texcoord;
    out vec3 Color;
    out vec2 Texcoord;
    void main()
    {
        Color = color;
        Texcoord = texcoord;
        gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);
    }
)glsl";
const GLchar* fragmentSource = R"glsl(
    #version 150 core
    in vec3 Color;
    in vec2 Texcoord;
    out vec4 outColor;
    uniform sampler2D tex0;
    void main()
    {
        outColor = texture(tex0, Texcoord) * vec4(Color, 1.0);
    }
)glsl";
```

I noticed that the proposed shaders couldn't compile in my computer, since my GLsl version is 1.30, but changing the version declaration into

```
#version 130 core
```

the ouput of this instruction is `glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, 512, NULL, infoLog)`;

> 0:2(10): error: illegal text following version number

I wuould like to understand what is wrong in this shader (in version 1.30) or at least where to find enough information to "repair" this situation.
Thanks

**#UPDATE 1**
I managed to have compiling shaders with no errors, but still the program does not work.

```
// Shader sources
//in --> attribute
//out --> varying
const GLchar* vertexSource = R"glsl(
    #version 130
    attribute vec2 position;
    attribute vec3 color;
    attribute vec2 texcoord;
    varying vec3 Color;
    varying vec2 Texcoord;
    void main()
    {
        Color = color;
        Texcoord = texcoord;
        gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);
    }
)glsl";

//in --> varying
//out --> (delete)
const GLchar* fragmentSource = R"glsl(
    #version 130
    varying vec3 Color;
    varying vec2 Texcoord;
    uniform sampler2D tex0;
    void main()
    {
       gl_FragColor = texture2D(tex0, Texcoord) * vec4(Color, 1.0);
    }
)glsl";
```

I used some functions like this to confirm that shaders are successfully compiled and linked

```
int success; char infoLog[512];
glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success); 
//can also use GL_LINK_STATUS flag
if(!success)
{
    glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
    std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::VERTEX::COMPILATION_FAILED\n" << infoLog << std::endl;
    std::cout <<  glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION) << std::endl;
    std::cout <<  success << std::endl;
};
```

Comment: I'm guessing a bit, so you will have to try around. However, you probably don't need the `core` annotation, i'm not even sure it exists for version 130. I couldn't find anything on the fly that would confirm this though.
Some older versions don't support `texture` for access of textures, so you may need a `texture2D` here. 
All that being said, are your sure your glsl version is 130? That is extremely old. What kind of graphics card are you using?

Comment: @Tare thank you. I will try your suggestion. I am sure about glsl version, confirmed both from line code glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION) and from terminal (glxinfo |grep version). Not sure about the graphics card, because the core runs under a virtual machine.

Answer (score 4):

There is no such thing as a core profile in GLSL 1.30. The concept of API profiles was introduced with OpenGL 3.2 which happened after GLSL 1.30 was released. The syntax for the version specification in [GLSL 1.30](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.1.30.pdf) is

```
#version <number>
```

Apart from that, I highly recommend that you check to confirm that GLSL 1.30 *really* is the maximum version you're supposed to be able to use on your system. It seems not unlikely that you just don't have a proper OpenGL driver installed. Even software implementations like MESA support more recent versions than that these days…

Comment: Thanks, the provided syntax has been very useful. I checked about version, under the virtual machine the version number of GLSL is 1.30 and 99% i will not allowed to update the drivers, even if it is possible. (yes, I am forced to work under this virtual machine)

Comment: Well, if this is a virtual machine which you can't change and are forced to use, then I guess 1.30 is, unfortunately, indeed what you're stuck with…